Snowflake VSCode connector : Cannot execute code. Unable to start a runtime for the Snowflake SQL language
Using the official Snowflake connector to connect to Snowflake from VScode.
Steps followed:

install the extension

inserted my data and connected with SSO.

Verified that the connection was successful : I am able to see the available tables for instance.

Create a .sql file and run select "test" as test ;


Output message: Cannot execute code. Unable to start a runtime for the Snowflake SQL language.

Check in Snowflake with the user that  you are using in VSS and see if you can execute the SQL.

@HimanshuKandpal yes it is the same user and I can execute.
